# Data Factory git - how to revert to latest published version

Tags: git, azure-data-factory

I am using Data Factory V2 with git integration. I am developing in browser, from the Azure Portal. So far I kept making new changes, testing, publishing.

Today I am in the situation that I made some bad changes.
Those are not yet published to the master branch.
Is there any way to discard the most recent changes == revert to master?

Many thanks!!

Looking for an easy way to revert to master branch, from the web UI.
By that I mean less effort than dropping one pipeline + source + destination + schedule and re-creating from scratch.
Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried to find the clean version from the publish? By default, the name of the publish branch is `adf_publish`

Answer (score 0):

You can use git reset to revert that branch to a prior state, you can do this with the cloudshell/powershell but not with the UX.

Even though this doc is from azure devops, it should be valid for github as well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/undo?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2022

Also getting Github for your OS and cloning your collab branch enables you to see any change that has been done and which JSON was affected.

Right clicking on a commit, and clicking 'revert commit' reverses the selected change. Push it back to your remote git repository, and refresh your page on ADF to see the changes reflected.

If you want to selectively undo, you have to change the JSON yourself in order to partially undo a commit.

use the line-by-line differences provided by git (in your most recent changes) in order to identify / isolate your changes, adjust them & push these changes back to the collaboration branch.\